# How to find classes by annotation on classpath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

On startup of a `spring-boot` application I want to perform a scan for all `@Entitiy` classes on the classpath.

Moreover, I'd like to filter any entities with a `@CustomAnnotation`.

I want to create some kind of auto configuration, and use the package of any entities found in:

```
EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
  .dataSource(ds)
  .packages(getPackages()))
```

But I don't want to explicit define the package there the appropriate entities are to be found, but find them on startup. Is that possible at all?

Comment: There is a utility scannotation which can assist, if you can use third parties

Comment: @Robertiano thanks, this seems to be a duplicate. Thus I voted byself to close accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer but in order to have the annotations on the compiled class files, they must be defined as follows `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [java-reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library to search for annotated classes, methods or classes extending another class across all loaded class files